# Solr SIH: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm getting this message:

> Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

In order to fill this field on each document, I'm using:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="files-update-processor">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    ...
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

By default, this `files-update-processor`, is chained into any `update`:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">files-update-processor</str>
    </lst>
</initParams>
```

By other side, I've configured this data import handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

For each document that this `DIH` is indexing, I'm getting this message:

```
o.a.s.h.d.SolrWriter Error creating document : {code_l_ns=code_l_ns=3160, title_txt_ca=title_txt_ca=Ps. Verdaguer, voreres modificació} => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
```

My `data-config.xml` is:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.122.1;databaseName=giac_txt" user="sa" password="StR0nGp4ss."/>
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="select codi_unitat, titol from anc_unicat">
            <field column="codi_unitat" name="code_l_ns"/>
            <field column="titol" name="title_txt_ca" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I remember the `update.chain` needs to specified on the `/dataimport` endpoint directly, so add `<str name="update.chain">files-update-processor</str>` under `<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `schema.xml` check if you defined the field with `"id"`.
The field you have mentioned id as `required = true`.

The document that you are trying to index in SOLR using the data-config also do not contain this `id` field and hence SOLR is throwing this error.

The Solution to the problem could be :

Add `id` field to all your documents

OR

Remove `required = true` form schema file for `id` field.

Please do share your `schema.xml` file.